# Extract day and month from a datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column with dates in string format `'2017-01-01'`. Is there a way to extract day and month from it using pandas?

I have converted the column to `datetime dtype` but haven't figured out the later part:

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df.dtypes: 
Date        datetime64[ns]

print(df)

         Date
0   2017-05-11
1   2017-05-12
2   2017-05-13
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With `dt.day` and `dt.month` --- [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01',periods=5)})
df.date.dt.month
Out[164]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: date, dtype: int64

df.date.dt.day
Out[165]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Also can do with [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
df.date.dt.strftime('%m')
Out[166]: 
0    01
1    01
2    01
3    01
4    01
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 22):

A simple form:

```
df['MM-DD'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.month)
```

Comment: I get this error: ```df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'day' ``` What is wrong here????

Answer (score 2):

Use `dt` to get the `datetime` attributes of the column.

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime.datetime(2018,1,1),datetime.datetime(2018,1,2),datetime.datetime(2018,1,3),]})

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
        date
0 2018-01-01
1 2018-01-02
2 2018-01-03

In [63]: df['day'] = df.date.dt.day

In [64]: df['month'] = df.date.dt.month

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
        date  day  month
0 2018-01-01    1      1
1 2018-01-02    2      1
2 2018-01-03    3      1
```

Timing the methods provided:

Using `apply`:

```
In [217]: %timeit(df['date'].apply(lambda d: d.day))
The slowest run took 33.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop
```

Using `dt.date`:

```
In [218]: %timeit(df.date.dt.day)
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
```

Using `dt.strftime`:

```
In [219]: %timeit(df.date.dt.strftime('%d'))
The slowest run took 40.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 284 µs per loop
```

We can see that `dt.day` is the fastest