# Cannot extract day/month/year from a timestamp (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp of the following format: "10-27-2022 4:00:00 AM". I want to find a way to get the day, month, year and store them on three different variables. I am following this procedure: [Extract day and month from a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603690/extract-day-and-month-from-a-datetime-object) and more specifically Peybae's code:

```
df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.month)
```

The part of my code, that causes me problems is this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
    df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.month)
    print("day = ", df['day'])
    print("month =", df['month'])
```

And this is the error:

```
    df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'day'
```

I have tried many combinations without success. What is wrong?? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the data type of your `df['Date']`. The code from your link only works if `df['Date']` is a datetime object. It appears that your `df['Date']` is a string, which is the cause of the error. You will have to convert the string in your `df['Date']` to a datetime object before extracting day, month, etc. You shall be able to find online how to convert a date time string to a datetime object in Python.